# Python: How to get values of an array at certain index positions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array like this:

```
a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]
```

How can I get the values at certain index positions in ONE step? For example:

```
ind_pos = [1,5,7]
```

The result should be:

```
[88,85,16]
```

Comment: a is not a numpy array in the question but a simple list

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just index using you `ind_pos`

```
ind_pos = [1,5,7]
print (a[ind_pos]) 
[88 85 16]


In [55]: a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]

In [56]: import numpy as np

In [57]: arr = np.array(a)

In [58]: ind_pos = [1,5,7]

In [59]: arr[ind_pos]
Out[59]: array([88, 85, 16])
```

Comment: Ah it has to be a numpy array. If I try it like this, it doesn´t work:
    a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]
    ind_pos = [1,5,7]
    a[ind_pos]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<ipython-input-121-92d3ce287d9d>", line 1, in <module>
    a[ind_pos]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

But if I add the line "arr = np.array(a)", it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, I presumed `a` was a numpy array. Yes a would need to be a numpy array

Answer (score 23):

The one liner "no imports" version

```
a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]
ind_pos = [1,5,7]
[ a[i] for i in ind_pos ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Although you ask about `numpy` arrays, you can get the same behavior for regular Python lists by using `operator.itemgetter`.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]
>>> ind_pos = [1, 5, 7]
>>> print itemgetter(*ind_pos)(a)
(88, 85, 16)
```

Comment: is this or numpy faster?

Comment: It depends. If you already have a NumPy array, that should be faster. If you have to *construct* a NumPy array from your list first, the time it takes to do that and the selection may be slower than it would be to simply operate on the list.

Comment: There really should be a way to do this without having to call in a package

Answer (score 5):

You can use [index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays), simply pass your `ind_pos` as an index argument as below:

```
a = np.array([0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91])
ind_pos = np.array([1,5,7])

print(a[ind_pos])
# [88,85,16]
```

Index arrays do not necessarily have to be numpy arrays, they can be also be lists or any sequence-like object (though not tuples).

Answer (score -2):

your code would be

`a = [0,88,26,3,48,85,65,16,97,83,91]`

`ind_pos = [a[1],a[5],a[7]]`

`print(ind_pos)`

you get [88, 85, 16]