# appending from a list of listts

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
beerlist =
[['', 'beer', 'uerige-doppel-sticke', '46158', ''],
     ['', 'beer', 'schumacher-1838er', '211568', ''],
     ['', 'beer', 'schlussel-stike', '53106', '']]
```

and I would like to iterate through the list and print the 3rd value from each entry.

I can access this individually, for example:

```
beerList[2][3]
```

But when I try to iterate through the list:

```
for beer in beerList:
    print(beer[2])
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think I am misunderstanding something about accessing objects in a loop, what am I not getting here?

Comment: the example `beerlist` you posted here would not raise the error you are describing. Please match the example and behaviour so that we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to get values of an array at certain index positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201438/python-how-to-get-values-of-an-array-at-certain-index-positions)

Comment: The exception is not raised with the given list of lists, but you probably modified it somehow (or assigned a new value).

Comment: Also note that the Python is case-sensitive. `beerList` is not the same as `beerlist`

Comment: You are quite right. Solved it. Turns out on closer inspection there was an entry in the original list that had less than 3 entries, which was giving the 'out of range error'. In the end I needed to pop that entry off before running the loop. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You're, given the way you posed the question, not doing anything wrong. For your given list, the loop

```
for beer in beerlist:
    print(beer[2])
```

works well. You either have a list where the elements (themselves list) are not all of length >2 and as such the third element does not exist, raising the described error. Another possibility, because you mentioned `beerlst[2][3]` is that you confused the order of accessing elemenets, as this accesses the fourth element of the third list, and not the third element of the fourth list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo in variable name:

```
beerlist =
[['', 'beer', 'uerige-doppel-sticke', '46158', ''],
     ['', 'beer', 'schumacher-1838er', '211568', ''],
     ['', 'beer', 'schlussel-stike', '53106', '']]
```

and then you try to access it by `beerList[2][3]`

and `beerList`is not `beerlist` as Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
for beer in range(len(beerList)):
    print(beerList[beer][2])
```

You forgot to use the iterable as an index

Also as pointed out by some users, there is a typo in the list definition.

Comment: Fixed the iteration

Comment: that is no different from the original loop,  which actually works fine if you ignore the typo.

Comment: True. I didn’t see the list definition typo until now. Just wanted to provide a working alternative