# Python: How to get values of a multi-dimensional array at certain indexed positions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

If I have a multi-dimensional numpy array like:

```
a = [[0 1 2]
     [3 4 5]
     [6 7 8]]
```

How can I get the values at certain index positions in one step? For example, if were to define pairs of indices like:

```
indices = [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]]
```

I would like:

```
a[indices] = [0, 4, 8]
```

Note that this does work for one-dimensional arrays ([Python: How to get values of an array at certain index positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201438/python-how-to-get-values-of-an-array-at-certain-index-positions)), but I cannot see how to get this to work in more than one dimension. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: `[ a[pair[0]][pair[1]] for pair in indices ]`

Comment: `a[ [0,1,2], [0,1,2] ]`.  Use a list or array for each dimensiion.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the one-dimensional answer you linked, you can do this elegantly in 2 dimensions with [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/index.html):

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
rows, columns = zip([0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2])
print(a[rows, columns])
```

The output of the `print` will be:

```
array([0, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from Prasanna's comment

```py
a = [[0 1 2]
     [3 4 5]
     [6 7 8]]
indices = [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]]

a[indices] = [a[pair[0]][pair[1]] for pair in indices]
```

This works by using a for each loop, iterating through each pair in the array of indices, and then adding the values at each given index to your final result.

`pair` is each pair in the indices array, and represents each index pair in `indices`. In your example, it will be `[0,0]` in the first iteration, `[1,1]` in the second, and `[2,2]` in the third.

Comment: Just so you know, you can not do `a[indices]`. Although the RHS of the assignment will give you the things you need, the LHS of the assignment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not in my best state of mind right now, but I will take a look at it and update my answer accordingly once I get a bit of sleep and can wrap my mind around what you're saying. Just to clarify, LHS/RHS = left/right hand side? Also, how tf do I add a line break to a comment. \n and <br> aren't working, and enter key just saves the comment.